# Problema con la reacción del emoji

Tags: javascript, nodejs, discord.js

Estoy creando un mensaje que cuando se reaccione le otorgue el rol en Discord, me carga bien las reacciones pero me da un error en sintaxis.

```
TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.
```

El código que tengo el error es este:

```js
const emojis = {'♂':'Reaction man', '♀':'Reaction female'}
const reactions = []

let emojiText = 'Add a reaction to claim your role @here!!!\n\n'
for (const key in emojis) {
    const emoji = key
    reactions.push(emoji)

    const role = emojis[key]
    emojiText += `${emoji} = ${role}\n`
}
```

Lo que estoy intentado es que pueda usar cualquier emoji antes cargaba los del canal y funcionaba pero quiero que sea con los normales.

Este es el código anterior.

```js
const getEmoji = (emojiName) =>
    client.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => emoji.name === emojiName)

const emojis = {
    male_sign: '♂',
    female_sign: '♀',
}
  
const reactions = []

let emojiText = 'Add a reaction to claim your role @here!!!\n\n'
for (const key in emojis) {
    //const emoji = key
    const emoji = getEmoji(key)
    reactions.push(emoji)

    const role = emojis[key]
    emojiText += `${emoji} = ${role}\n`
}
```